# Select range of dates from calendar using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, calendar

I have a webpage where I need to select dates in a range. Like in the picture [Calendar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Nrr.png)

But the problem is I need to first click on the start date and then move the mouse to the end date and click on it again.

I tried to find the xpath of the specific element to try this with this code-

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]").click()`

But it selects the element with a 1st click and doesn't work. I know this is not the best method and I am new to Selenium and python.

Any Help is higly appreciated.

The inspect element on that date looks like this-

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI6Iy.png)

P.s It is no use to put text in the date, I tried it but doesn't work

```
    x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    x.clear()
    x.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    x.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    x.send_keys("15-02-18")

    y=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input")
    y.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    y.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    y.send_keys("22-02-18")
    y.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

`

Comment: sorry @DeliriousLettuce, its inside cashcowpro account from Amazon and I cannot share the login information here..:(

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I can tell you one thing that it works similar to the calendar in https://www.kayak.com/

Comment: You need to use the day as a text to figure out the element to click on. There is a huge difference in the DOM of kayak and the amazon site. Without actual html pretty hard to find out exact locators. Anyways to select for example the '21 March' on kayak use the xpath - `//div[@aria-hidden='false']//div[@class='col-day'][@aria-label='March 21']/div[@class='day'][.='21']`. Use relative xpaths rather than absolute ones. Maybe this helps u out.

Comment: @Grasshopper you were right that there is a huge difference in both and I cannot apply the same thing for both. But is there anything else that I can do. I am stuck at this point and cannot just move forward.

Comment: Try this xpath for selecting date on the left sided calendar - `//div[@class='calendar left']/div[@class='calendar-table']//td[contains(@class,'available')][.='16']`. Try in console and check if it selects 16 Feb

Comment: @Grasshopper your methods work perfectly for selecting the 16th date on the left calendar.

Thank you. 

But .click() method attached to it works as double click instead of single click. Do you know how can I single click on 16 and then go to 22 and do a single click again?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by double click. Does it deselect that date as it is current date? Try with 15 or some other date?

Comment: Actually, your method works perfectly for selecting the date, but in the application, if I need to have dates selected in the range 16-22 feb, I need to first click on 16th and then go to 22nd and click on 22nd to select the range 16-22feb.
And if you click twice on 16th, it gives you information on that particular date instead of the range.

But now when I select 16th and then click on it and then select 22nd and then click on it, it shows the data for the 16th and not the range of 16-22. 

but anyways can you put your comment with selecting the date in answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: What do u mean by 'select and click'. Avoid double clicks. Just find the element with xpath and use click method. What is the manual technique of selecting range. Do u need to use the mouse with with the button pressed etc? Will add as answer.

Comment: @Grasshopper could I have your LinkedIn ID so that I could use the chat platform with images to make it clearer? I will delete the message as soon as I read it.

Comment: Sorry this may be strange but got not LinkedIn. Better you add it on here.

Comment: 'e1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='calendar left']/div[@class='calendar-table']//td[contains(@class,'available')][.='12']")`
`e1.click()`
`time.sleep(3)`

`add=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='calendar left']/div[@class='calendar-table']//td[contains(@class,'available')][.='23']")`
`ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(add).perform()`

`add.click()'

the final code that worked. Thank you so much for all your inputs. I learned a lot about setting paths through div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath for selecting date on the left sided calendar -

`//div[@class='calendar left']/div[@class='calendar-table']//td[contains(@class,'available')][.='16'].`

Try in console and check if it selects 16 Feb